# Catalyst Template-Toolkit failures when AUTHOR_TESTING or RELEASE_TESTING variables are set

Tags: perl, catalyst, template-toolkit

I have a Catalyst application that uses Template Toolkit.

We recently decided to reorganise some of the tests so that some are skipped unless AUTHOR_TESTING or RELEASE_TESTING variables are set (which would be set for automated continuous integration tests).

Apparently when either the AUTHOR_TESTING or RELEASE_TESTING is set, some of the pages die with an error in the Catalyst view rendering stage:

> Couldn't render template "[path to template]: undef error - "

A bit of searching on the web found something about enabling debugging at http://lists.scsys.co.uk/pipermail/catalyst/2007-March/012548.html but this is unhelpful.

I've run a grep for these environment variables in the installed Perl modules and Carton local library, in the hopes of finding the code that uses them.  They only seem to be referenced by testing and Module-Build.

Can anyone help with identifying the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of exploration and trial and error, it turns out that a custom method in the view (added to the template using `expose_methods`) died via Devel::StrictMode.

Comment: This is in part due to Catalyst::View::TT not catching errors and propagating them upwards.

Comment: I've submitted a patch to Catalyst::View::TT that catches these errors, which was included in v0.46.